# Using Wiremock standalone, how can I define default headers?

Tags: wiremock, wiremock-standalone

I have a setup where I run Wiremock standalone (as a Docker container, if that matters), with mappings defined in JSON files.

Is there a way to specify certain headers that will be applied to all responses? Specifically, I want all responses to have `Content-Type: application/json`, without having to repeat it in each mapping.